# WPF Binding a Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I am having an issue binding a dependency property in a UserControl. When it initializes it gets a value but then it will not update.  I've probably missed something obvious, here are some code snippets:

This is where I bind the `BalanceContent` dependency property:

```
<Game:PlayerDetails x:Name="SelectedPlayerDetails" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                          BalanceContent="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=SelectedUser.Balance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

    </Game:PlayerDetails>
```

Here is the `TextBox` in the `UserControl`:

```
 <TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BalanceContent}" 
             Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

Here is the Dependency Property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BalanceContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BalanceContent", typeof(string), typeof(PlayerDetails));

    public string BalanceContent
    {
        get
        {return (string) GetValue(BalanceContentProperty);}
        set
        {SetValue(BalanceContentProperty, value);}
    }
```

Here is the list where the selected user is updated, which is in a view that uses the UserControl:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstAccounts"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=CurrentUserSearch}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=SelectedUser}"
```

And `SelectedUser` is defined here in a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
 public User SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUser;
        } 
        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedUser"));
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the TextBox should update when a new user is selected in the list but at the moment it is not doing so.  I've put the binding on local TextBox and it updates fine, just not on a `DependencyProperty`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some possibilities you could try:

First, your ListView may not be updating yours ViewModel's SelectedUser property. Try setting the binding in your ListView to "TwoWay" mode:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstAccounts"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=CurrentUserSearch}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

You can organize better the way the DataContext's are defined. Remember that all the child controls of your UserControl will have access to its DataContext without the use of relative binding (they inherit it). As your PlayerInfo control depends on the SelectedUser, consider setting it's DataContext to the SelectedUser, either binding it to the SelectedUser of the ListView or the SelectedUser in the   UserData viewmodel.

```
 <Game:PlayerDetails x:Name="SelectedPlayerDetails" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=SelectedUser}"
                      BalanceContent="{Binding Balance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

</Game:PlayerDetails>
```

The source of the current SelectedUser could also be the ListView:

```
<Game:PlayerDetails x:Name="SelectedPlayerDetails" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstAccounts}"
                      BalanceContent="{Binding Balance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

</Game:PlayerDetails>
```

Either way, you will then be able to do the following on the TextBox, because its DataContext will be the same as the one of its parent:

```
<TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
     Text="{Binding Balance}" 
         Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

If the usercontrol depends on the root viewmodel for things like commands and other high level logic, then set the DataContext to it in a way you can easily access the SelectedUser.

```
<Game:PlayerDetails x:Name="SelectedPlayerDetails" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" DataContext="{StaticResource UserData}"
                      BalanceContent="{Binding SelectedUser.Balance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

</Game:PlayerDetails>
```

So you can do this:

```
<TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
     Text="{Binding SelectedUser.Balance}" 
         Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

In this second approach, however, you will have to check one thing I'm not sure about. I know that when the DataContext of a control changes, it will update all the dependent bindings allright. For example, if you changed the PlayerDetails DataContext to another UserData instance, the BalanceContent property would update as well. However, in this case the BalanceContent depends on property of the SelectedUser of the UserData. So it will listen to Property changes of that instance of User. If the SelectedUser.Balance changes (and User implements INotifyPropertyChanged, or it is a DependencyProperty), BalanceContent will update. Now, if the SelectedUser instance in the UserData changes, I'm not sure BalanceContent will update, because I think that a binding does not listen to changes of every object in its path.

**EDIT**

The last point was perhaps the first problem I hit when developing with xaml. I had a DataGrid in Silverlight whose entity type had a property of a complex type. One of the columns depended on a property of the complex type. If I changed the value of the complex type, the column would update fine (it implemented INPC). If I changed the complex type instance of an entity, the column would not... The solution was to cascade DataContexts: I created a template column, set the binding of the column for the complex type, instead of its property. Then I bound the text of the TextBox of my template to the property of the complextype, because it was now the TextBox's DataContext.

In your case you can do it for the TextBox.Text, but not for the PlayerDetails.BalanceContent. You can bind the TextBox.DataContext to the SelectedUser of the UserData and then bind Text to the Balance property.

```
<TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding SelectedUser}" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
 Text="{Binding Balance}" 
     Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a quick comment before I go over the entire post in detail. The selecteduser in the ViewModel is getting updated as that was one of the first things I thought. I also have a TextBox that is a member of the window that updates the balance fine with the same binding as I'm using on the dependency property.  The value is initialized fine but with subsequent updates the value in the control's TextBox remains the same so I think your last point warrants further investigation

Comment: So changing the source of the SelectedUser to the ListView worked even though XAML complains about not being able to resolve Balance, which I guess at design time it obviously will do.

Answer (score 1):

Please try testing after changing your binding for text box inside your user control to bind to BalanceContent which is User Controls Dependency Property (your original binding source seems to be data context property)

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BalanceContent}"
```

EDIT: Please try the following code

```
public User SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUser;
        } 
        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedUser"));
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedUserBalance"));
        }
    }

public string SelectedUserBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUser.Balance;
        } 
    }

<Game:PlayerDetails x:Name="SelectedPlayerDetails" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                          BalanceContent="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData}, Path=SelectedUserBalance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

</Game:PlayerDetails>

<TextBox  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
         Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=BalanceContent}"
             Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but it behaves in the same way.

Comment: I've edited my coded to reflect your suggestion, at least the source is more obvious.  However, it still works as before, where the value is update on initialize but not when the value changes.

Comment: Yes, the reason for updating binding was that the original binding source was bound to a property on DataContext but it seemed like it is a dependency property of your custom control.

Could you please post your Dependency Property code?

Comment: Could you please create another property on your ViewModel, let's call it SelectedUserBalance and use this property as a source for BalanceContent property of your control?
Also update SelectedUser to include OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedUserBalance")); every time it's set.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code for the dependency property. Adding SelectedUserBalance property didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The Textbox is trying to bind to the UserControls `DataContext`. give an `x:Name` to the Usercontrol definition and set the TextBox's DataContext to `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=[YourControlName]}"`

Comment: Thanks for the input but still behaves the same with those changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Formata" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" 
       Text="{Binding SelectedItem.BalanceContent, ElementName=lstAccounts}" Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>
```

forget binding of UserControl , Directly bind TextBox to SelectedItem . I hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. lstAccounts is a view that uses the UserControl that the TextBox is part of.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a StaticResource to the property. StaticResources, as opposed to DynamicResources, are loaded only once, when the Window (or UserControl) is being initialised. DynamicResources are loaded only when needed (and each time when needed). Any change that is made to a DynamicResource is picked up immediately and the property is updated accordingly. Simply replace the keyword "StaticResource" with "DynamicResource", and the property binding should update each time the resource changes.

Note: If the StaticResource is an object that derives from the Freezable class, it will also behave somewhat like a DynamicResource. For example, if your resource is a Brush, the bound property will update each time you change the Brush object in any way (by changing its opacity, for example), but this is due to the behaviour inherited from the Freezable class. However if you replace the Brush object in the StaticResource by a new Brush object, *this* change won't be picked up, because the change has been made to the Resource, which is Static, not the Brush.

Also Note: Even resources that are only available as StaticResources, such as data SystemColors, SystemFonts (which provide access to system settings) can be wrapped in a DynamicResource to ensure that the property is updated at each change. This can be done this way:

`<Control Property="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.XXX}}"></Control>`.